# Protect screws in joint and make it look nicer?

Tags: wood, joints, pressure-treated

So this is what the joint looks like.

It's solid, but as you can see, the screws are exposed so they'll be rusting pretty soon. Also, the joint looks horrible. It's PT wood.

What can I buy to make it look nicer, and the same time, strengthen it?

[image]

Comment: I'm 99.999% sure I'd be replacing those boards before I spent significant time cobbling up a mask for their degraded state. To what do they connect?

Comment: They're not degraded. It's just that this particular joint was not well done, but the wood is new. I'm looking for something that I can use to fill it up.

Comment: In my opinion, both those board are degraded badly, if only by poor workmanship, and there's only one right solution. Putty isn't it.

Comment: Not sure why screws rusting is even a question. Use deck screws or similar that are designed to be outside forever and should last several years. Which is longer than the wood based on the looks of it.

Answer (score 1):

Is that a hand rail of some sort? I would not want PT wood on a hand rail, the chemicals used to treat it are dangerous for human skin contact. If it is a hand rail, I would get a better untreated wood that can cover over the entire arrangement, then use a safe stain or sealant on that new wood. Offset the joints so that they don't line up with these joints and you kill two birds with one stone.

Answer (score 0):

That joint is not very strong and it wouldn’t take much to blow it out, replace the boards and use a half lap joint (  even a butt joint with wood that doesn’t have it Ends all chewed up would be better than that ) and  use exterior grade  deck screws that won’t rust,  they are made to withstand the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Get some DAP woodfiller from any home improvement store and fill the holes and then sand it smooth. Then if I was you, I would paint it to make it look nicer, because it wont look great, but the screw will be covered.